# Missing ProcessParameterMetadata in TFS DefaultTemplate.xaml: where is for e.g. Items to Build in the Required category

Tags: build, tfs, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to figure out how the Windows Workflow Foundation (WWF) template provided by default for builds in TFS specifies the Build process parameters in a build definition.

This should happen via the `ProcessParameterMetadataCollection` and the `ProcessParameterMetadata` contained therein. However nowhere in the DefaultTemplate.xaml are they specified. There's no *Required* category or *Items to Build* item anywhere, and none of the others circled in red either. See picture below.

I thought maybe they were specified in an attached workflow, alas my knowledge of WWF isn't that good and I can't find any attached workflows. Then I thought perhaps they might be specified in code as part of the build in activities. I have no idea, does anybody know?

[image: Build process parameters missing in TFS DefaultTemplate.xaml]

Answer (score 1):

When you open up a build XAML file, near the bottom there are *Variables*, *Arguments*, and *Imports* links that you can click. If you click the *Arguments* link, this is where these exist. If they don't show up right away, it means you are out of the correct activity scope. If you click different activities in the build, you'll see the arguments list change. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I am aware of those sneaky links at the bottom of the designer. I was using xaml, however the issue I'm referring to can be seen in the designer too. In the *Arguments* link there is a *MetaData* property of type `ProcessParameterMetadataCollection`, which allow you to add or remove items from the *Build process parameters* in the build definition - as per the picture above. If you edit this collection in the designer you will see that for e.g. the *Items to Build* item is missing.

Comment: The _Items to Builds_ parameter is stored in the `BuildSettings` argument. This is a global argument that contains HasPlatformConfigurations, HasProjectsToBuild, PlatformConfigurations, and ProjectsToBuild. In the _Arguments_ tab of the XAML, it should be the very top argument. Here's a link to the class documentation on MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.buildsettings.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.buildsettings.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I see that internally `BuildSettings` uses some attributes: `TypeConverter`, `Editor`, `SRDescription`,  `RefreshProperties` and `Browsable` and I guess one of these is indirectly responsible for providing the descriptions in the *Build process parameters*. I came across this [LINK](http://devtfs.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/reusable-editors-tfs-build-arguments/) with some info on using the Editor attribute. I'll accept your answer, if you expand it to include the bit about the `BuildSettings` argument displaying the *Build process parameters*. Also any extra info would be appreciated.