# How to put build process parameters into categories in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I open up a build definition I can see the arguments are split into sections with a number prefix e.g. 1. Basic, 2. Misc etc.

However, when I edit the xaml there is no indication as to where these categories are defined.
Can someone provide some guidance as to where they are located within the arguments list?

Here is a similar question except the poster has inquired about a different parameter based off the build settings which I believe is a different case than regular parameters.

[Missing ProcessParameterMetadata in TFS DefaultTemplate.xaml: where is for e.g. Items to Build in the Required category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880740/missing-processparametermetadata-in-tfs-defaulttemplate-xaml-where-is-for-e-g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the build template and edit the Metadata argument as shown in the picture below:
[image]

Then you can edit the category:
[image]

In the XML there is no category as standalone. You can define the category in the Process.Metadata section:

```
<this:Process.Metadata>
<mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection>
  <mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadata Category="#300 Advanced" Description="Enable MSBuid Multi-proc to build your solutions' projects in parallel, when possible, using all available processors on the build server." DisplayName="MSBuild Multi-Proc" ParameterName="MSBuildMultiProc" />
  ....

</mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection>
</this:Process.Metadata>
```

This is to add new categorys but i dont know where the standard categories are.

Hope that helped you.

Chears

Comment: Information on categories can be found here:
[MSDN Blogs: TFS 2010 – Ordering the Build Process Parameters On The Definition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/11/30/tfs-2010-ordering-the-build-process-parameters-on-the-definition.aspx).
"The category string we use is actually “#300 Advanced” The ‘#’ at the front tells the code that the first part of the string is a priority number. Notice that we use 300 here. Required is 100, Basic is 200, and Advanced is 300. That allows space for you to put your own categories before or in between ours."