# Default array content in build process

Tags: tfs, build-process

I have added a new argument into the argument-list, which should have default values.
It is declared as a `System.String[]` but I can't figure out how to give it values. Giving values through Queue new Build works fine, but it is time taking to type in all values each time.
I guess it's pretty simple but I just can't figure out how the Syntax is working while editing a build process.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to Metadata and change the item of **View this parameter when** dropdownlist in **Process Parameter metadata** editor (e.g. Only while editing a definition).

You also can specify default value of that parameter when edit build process template, such as {"str1","str2"}.

There is a similar thread: [How to put build process parameters into categories in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576380/how-to-put-build-process-parameters-into-categories-in-tfs)